# Find all unique attribute sets of a given length greater than a certain threshold in a csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I have this dataset: https://s3.amazonaws.com/istreet-questions-us-east-1/443605/census.csv

```
age=Middle-aged,sex=Male,education=Bachelors,native-country=United-States,race=White,marital-status=Never-married,workclass=State-gov,occupation=Adm-clerical,hours-per-week=Full-time,income=Small,capital-gain=Low,capital-loss=None
age=Senior,sex=Male,education=Bachelors,native-country=United-States,race=White,marital-status=Married-civ-spouse,workclass=Self-emp-not-inc,occupation=Exec-managerial,hours-per-week=Part-time,income=Small,capital-gain=None,capital-loss=None
age=Middle-aged,sex=Male,education=HS-grad,native-country=United-States,race=White,marital-status=Divorced,workclass=Private,occupation=Handlers-cleaners,hours-per-week=Full-time,income=Small,capital-gain=None,capital-loss=None
```

30000 lines of this

Theres 12 variables basically and I want to create a function with 2 inputs (NumberOfAttributes, SupportThreshold).

So for example with input (4,.6) I want all 4 attribute combinations that comprise atleast 60% of the total data set.

I have found a solution but it is waaaaaaay too resource intensive. When I tried to submit it it said that it exceeded computation time requirement.

Here is my code:

```
def attributesSet(numberOfAttributes, supportThreshold):
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import itertools
    import math

    names = ['age','sex','education','country','race','status','workclass','occupation','hours-per-week','income','capital-gain','capital-loss']
    combinations = []
    final = []
    for comb in itertools.combinations(names,numberOfAttributes):
        combinations.append(list(comb))
    url = "https://s3.amazonaws.com/istreet-questions-us-east-1/443605/census.csv"
    c = pd.read_csv(url)
    c.columns= names
    total = len(c.index)
    required = math.ceil(supportThreshold*total)

    for i in combinations:
        g = c.groupby(i).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
        g
        groups = g[g>required].index
        satisfied = list(groups)
        for j in satisfied:
            final.append(','.join(j))

    return final
```

Basically, it creates a list of all the combinations of determined length and creates a pandas series that shows every single attribute based combination of that and the count.

Sample input:

```
2
0.8
```

Sample output:

```
race=White,capital-loss=None

native-country=United-States,race=White

native-country=United-States,capital-loss=None

native-country=United-States,capital-gain=None

capital-gain=None,capital-loss=None
```

all 2 attribute combinations that compose 80%+ of the dataset

There must be a way that isnt so resource intensive that I'm not seeing

Comment: Can you share an example with a subsample of the URL that would be small enough to be printed and the expected output ?

Comment: yep added it to the original post @SmileyProd

Answer (score 2):

There were two issues in the code.

1. It is exceeding computation time because you're loading the dataset from the URL. Instead, you should read the `census.csv`from current directory.
2. `.join(j)` in the code adds the `,` when the tuple has one parameter/group name.

Below is the working example.

```py
def attributesSet(numberOfAttributes, supportThreshold):
    import csv
    import pandas as pd
    import itertools
    import math

    names = ['age','sex','education','country','race','status','workclass','occupation','hours-per-week','income','capital-gain','capital-loss']
    combinations = []
    final = []
    for comb in itertools.combinations(names,numberOfAttributes):
        combinations.append(list(comb))
    c = pd.read_csv('census.csv')
    c.columns= names
    total = len(c.index)
    required = supportThreshold*total

    for i in combinations:
        g = c.groupby(i).size().sort_values(ascending=False)
        groups = g[g>required].index
        satisfied = list(groups)
        for j in satisfied:
            row = ''
            for t in j:
                row = row + t
                if j.index(t) != len(j)-1:
                    row = row + ','
            final.append(''+row)
    return final
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a URL to fetch the data is a very resource intense process. If you have tried loading the csv file from your disk it would be fairly fast.

Also there is a small bug in the code.

.join(j) in the last line doesn't work as expected when the "number of attributes" parameter is 1.

Since join function works on an iterative object, when it encounters a string it puts a "," between the letters of that string.